# How do I implement a blank parameter within SSMS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssms

I am building an SSRS report that includes 3 parameters (supplierid, startdate and enddate) but I am trying to implement an optional parameter (one that allows a blank value) called customerid. here is what I have for code:

```
WHERE  (invoice_hdr.company_no = 1) AND
       (supplier.supplier_id = @supplierid) AND
       (@customerid = 
          CASE @customerid
            WHEN customer.customer_id THEN customer.customer_id 
            ELSE 0
            END) AND
       (invoice_hdr.invoice_date >= DATEADD(DAY,-365,GETDATE()) AND
       --(invoice_hdr.invoice_date >= @startdate) AND
       --(invoice_hdr.invoice_date <= @enddate) AND
       (invoice_line.tax_item = 'N') AND
```

I am trying to say: IF a value is put into the customerid parameter then return that value with the other filters BUT if no value is placed in that parameter then bypass that filter and continue on running the query like it is not there. I have changed the parameter settings in SSRS to allow a blank/null value but the report errors out. Is there anyway to do this? is this an issue in SSRS?

I am having trouble doing this, any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE AFTER INCLUDING:

```
    (
    customer.customer_id = @customerid
    OR
    @customerid =''
    ) AND
```

and changing the parameter in SSRS this is the error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfFuu.png)

BUT if I run it without that parameter and section of code the report works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue is without the error message but I usually use something like:

```
AND (
    customer.customer_id = @customerid
    OR
    @customerid IS NULL
    )
```

This will include all IDs that match the parameter or ALL IDs if the parameter is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is to do this

```
AND (
    customer.customer_id = @customerid
    OR
    @customerid =''
    )
```

the on your customer parameters, set the parameter to

> Allow Blankvalue ("")

this way, if you do need to select the customer, you do not have to untick the NULL before using the parameter